# Stylecop SuppressMessage on specific namespace

Tags: c#, stylecop, suppressmessage

i got my enums collected in a namespace. Because of that, i have a *.cs file, that contains enums, no classes. Stylecop complains, and i want to supress it, but just for this file/namespace. Not globally, so i dont want to turn off the rule.

```
   [module:  System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("StyleCop.CSharp.DocumentationRules", "SA1649:FileHeaderFileNameDocumentationMustMatchTypeName", Scope = "namespace", Target = "SoftwareProject.Enums", Justification = "Reviewed.")]
   namespace SoftwareProject.Enums
   {
     // Enums here
   }
```

I can not get this SuppressMessage to work on just this namespace. Its works on the module, just like it does if i just delete the Scope and Target settings.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2):

I found my answer:

> The SuppressMessage attribute also takes the following optional parameters. These parameters are **completely ignored by StyleCop** and do not need to be filled in for StyleCop suppressions.
>
> > Message Id
> >
> > Scope
> >
> > Target

Source: StyleCop Help File. Found by right clicking on the warning -> Show Help.